# Coefficient of Maass cusp forms are bounded

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $$\phi(z)=\sum_{\gamma\in U_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash SL(2,\mathbb{Z})} \,\,\,\,\,\sum_{m_1=1}^{\infty}\,\,\sum_{m_2\neq 0}a(m,n)W_{\text{Jacquet}}\left(\begin{pmatrix} |m_1m_2| &  & \\
 & m_1 & \\
 & & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\gamma & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}z\,,\, \nu,\,\psi_{1,\frac{m_2}{|m_2|}} \right)$$ be a Maass cusp form of type $\nu=(\nu_1,\nu_2)$ for $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$. Show that $a(m,n)=O(1).$

Note that$$a(m,n)W_{\text{Jacquet}}\left(\begin{pmatrix} |m_1m_2|y_1y_2 &  & \\
 & m_1y_1 & \\
 & & 1 \end{pmatrix}\,,\, \nu,\,\psi_{1,\frac{m_2}{|m_2|}} \right)\\=\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\phi(z)e^{-2\pi i[m_1x_1+m+2x_2]}\,dx_1dx_2dx_3$$ If we knew that $\phi$ is bounded, then the claim would follow by choosing $y_1=c_1|m_1|^{-1}, y_2=c_2|m_2|^{-1}$ , but we only know that $\phi(z)$ is square integrable in the Seigel domain.

Comment: It's not true that $a(m,n) = O(1)$...

Comment: @PeterHumphries This is from Goldfeld's text 'Automorphic forms and L-functions for GL(n,R)', page 160.

Comment: You're missing the fact that Goldfeld is dividing through by $|mn|$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries $a(m,n)=A(m,n)/|mn|$ same thing right ?

Comment: @PeterHumphries also make sure that your definition of Maass forms agrees with his at page 115. Having said that, can you justify your earlier claim ?

Comment: Oh, with this normalisation the statement is correct. A Maass cusp form is bounded because obviously it is bounded on complex sets, while it is of rapid decay at the cusps due to the fact that it's a cusp form.